# How to delete all IAM role on AWS account

Tags: python

Step 1 :- export profile in your local terminal using command like
`export AWS_PROFILE=<your_profile_name>`

Step 2:- use below python code

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('iam')
response = client.list_roles()

for role_info in response['Roles']:
    try:
        delete_response = client.delete_role(RoleName=role_info['RoleName'])
        print("Deleting   :-   "+role_info['RoleName'])
    except:
        print("System defind role can't delete   :-   "+role_info['RoleName'])
```

Comment: what issue you are facing?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.